# displayMember and valueMember for input tag

Tags: html, input

I was wondering if I could have in HTML input element of text type, where one value that is displayed and another that is submited?

Comment: What would be the value that's displayed?  A user can type whatever they want in the input element right?

Comment: I will explain why do I need this. I want to make such input that when user enters character - another is displayed. That's for passwords - if user see characters but not asterisks, most likely he won't look for keyboard. Maybe idea is quite crazy, but still - is it possible to implement with input?

Comment: Why don't you just use `<input type=password>`?

Comment: because it will show asterisks, i would like to show another characters, I agree that is strange idea, but still.

Comment: I assume JS can be required?

Comment: Yes, JavaScript can be used.